# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found in Android Studio using TextFairy

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr

I am new to Android and i am trying an open source android project called Text Fairy in Android studio. https://github.com/renard314/textfairy. While i open the application in Android studio i get the

> "**Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found."**

I changed the ndk to path in my system as mentioned in the Git Hub.
I tried looking for the missing files but i couldn't find any of them.
I am using Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem got fixed finally.

The **Problem** was in the

- git submodule update
- git submodule init

There were errors in this two steps, When i run them in the reverse order it got fixed, ie

- git submodule init
- git submodule update

worked for me. Hope it helps others :)